# How can I show installed CSP's on my Linux system without using the cpconfig util?

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, cryptography

How can I show a list of installed Crypto Service Providers without using cpconfig or csptest? How can I check if there's a CSP on the current Linux system? The system is not mine and I'm told to escape installing new CSP's before making sure there's none existing on this machine. I've found several articles about how to do it with Windows register, but none - with Linux.
I'm using centOS 7, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux *does not have* a unified "Crypto Service Providers" architecture.

It seems that some commercial products, such as Crypto-Pro, emulate this architecture – but it exists *entirely within* that product. For example, Crypto-Pro documentation lists the main configuration file as `/etc/opt/cprocsp/config64.ini`, and I assume that's where the list of all installed CSPs would be kept.

But if you haven't yet installed this program, then no CSPs can exist within the system anyway.

Comment: I didn't install them, but my colleague could do that and he's not working with us anymore. But still, thank you for explanation.